# How do I write test for hooks?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I am making unit test for the component and also trying to make a test for hook but I can't seem to get it working. This is my hook. What do I need to change or do to fix this test?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function UseToggleState (initialValue = false) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);
  const toggle = () => setState(!state);

  return [state, toggle];
};

export default UseToggleState
```

And this is the component I am using it.

```
export function Todo({ id, task, completed }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const [isEditing, toggle] = useToggleState(false);

  if (isEditing) {
    return (
      <li
        className={classes.Todo}
        style={{ overflowY: "hidden" }}
        onClick={() => toggle()}
      >
        <EditForm id={id} task={task} toggleEditForm={toggle} />
      </li>
    );
  }

  return (
    <li
      className={classes.Todo}
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_TODO, id })}
    >
      <span
        style={{
          textDecoration: completed ? "line-through" : "",
          color: completed ? "#A9ABAE" : "#34495e",
        }}
      >
        {task}
      </span>
      <div className={classes.icons}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faPen}
          size="1x"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            toggle();
          }}
        />{" "}
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faTrash}
          size="1x"
          color={"#c0392b"}
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            dispatch({ type: REMOVE_TODO, id });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

And the test file is as follows. It keeps saying that toggle is not a function and I am not quite sure why it is doing that. Is there something I need to change differently to make it work?

```
describe("useToggleState", () => {
    it("Initial toggle is true", () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => UseToggleState(true))

        act(() => {
            result.current.toggle
        })

        expect(result.current.state).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it("Toggle is false", () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => UseToggleState(false))

        act(() => {
            result.current.toggle
        })

        expect(result.current.state).toBeFalsy()
    })
})
```

Comment: Which version of `react` and `react-test-renderer` are you using?

Comment: react is 16.13.1 and react-test-render is 16.13.1 @tmhao2005

Comment: I dropped the answer for you. BTW the test setup looks incorrect as well. The first test argument of the hook is supposed to be `true` like this: `renderHook(() => UseToggleState(true))`

Comment: I still get following error...   expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: undefined

      28 |         })
      29 |
    > 30 |         expect(result.current.toggle()).toBe(true)
         |                                         ^
      31 |     })
      32 | })

Comment: What are you doing by asserting this `expect(result.current.toggle()).toBe(true) `?

Comment: I updated my questions and test file part with latest version of it... I still get this in the console...  UseToggleState › Toggle is true

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: undefined

      13 |         })
      14 |
    > 15 |         expect(result.current.state).toBeTruthy()
         |                                      ^
      16 |         //expect(result.current.toggle()).toBeTruthy()
      17 |     })
      18 |

Comment: Your updates are incorrect. The original ones are accurate though. Why did you change?

Comment: I thought they were inaccurate so I changed..

Comment: No man. You did right but you need to input argument to be true in the first test. That’s it

Comment: I updated again and this is the error i get, what i have still wrong here?    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: undefined

      11 |         })
      12 |
    > 13 |         expect(result.current.state).toBeTruthy()
         |                                      ^
      14 |     })

Comment: I edited the test in the answer for you amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test is supposed to be:

```js
describe("useToggleState", () => {
  it("Initial toggle is false", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => UseToggleState(true))

    act(() => {
      result.current[1]()
    })

    expect(result.current[0]).toBe(false)
  })

  it("Toggle is true", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => UseToggleState())

    act(() => {
      result.current[1]()
    })

    expect(result.current[0]).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Comment: I guess I need to also change the TypeError: result.current.toggle is not a function because it keeps saying that it is not a function

Comment: Are you following the answer correctly? Did you change return value of the hook?

Comment: Yes but then whole application breaks

Comment: Okay. Jus keep the implementation the same. I've updated the test for you using the array instead the object